# Print results of a form on the same page in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In normal PHP, you can send a form on the same page:

```
<form action = "" method = "POST">
    <input type = "text" name = "hi" value = "hi"/>
    <input type = "submit" name = "send" value = "Send"/>
</form>
<?
   if (isset($_POST['send'])) 
   echo $_POST['hi'];
?>
```

How can I do this in CodeIgniter?

I've tried this, but I don't know how to do it:

**View:**

```
<? echo form_open('form'); ?>
.....
</form>
<?
if (isset($_POST['data'])){
    $array = $data;
    foreach ($array as $array){
       echo array_sum($array)/count($array)."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

**Controller:**

```
function index() {
    $name = $this->input->post('select');
    $this->load->model('select');
    $data['result'] = $this->select->index();
    $this->load->view('theview', $data);
}
```

Comment: After submiting the form it will go to the action controller there you can get the post data and then revert it to view...

Comment: did one of us answer your question...?

Answer (score 1):

You can submit the form using ajax request so that the page is not refreshed and the results are seen on the same page.Sample code ::
View :

```
 <?php
$attributes = array('id'=>'profile-form','name'=>'personal_pro_form');
echo form_open('update_user_profile',$attributes);?>
<label class="control-label myprofilefont" for="email"> Email Address:<em  class="colorred" >*</em></label>
  <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="user_email_id" value=>
                     ..
   <img src="submit-button.png"  id="Submit_Personal_Details">
   </form>
  $('#Submit_Personal_Details').live('click',function() {
  $.ajax({
             url:'update_user_profile',
            type:"POST",
            data:{'user_email_id':uemail,...},
            success:function(response){
            },
            error:function(req,status,error){
                alert(error);

            }
        });//end of ajax
```

}

Controller:

```
 function update_user_profile() {
... 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your view is at view/controller/index.php, then in your view, simply use

```
echo form_open('controller/index');
...

if(isset($hi))echo $hi
```

And in your controller/index method just put something like

```
function index() {
    if($_POST){
        if (isset($_POST['send'])){
            $this->set('hi', $_POST['hi']);
        }
    }else{
        $name = $this->input->post('select');
        $this->load->model('select');
        $data['result'] = $this->select->index();
        $this->load->view('theview', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this : 
**PHP**

```
function index(){

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="GET")
    {
        $data['hi'] = "";
    }else //if POST
    {
        $data['hi'] = $this->input->post("hi");
    }
    //load one view for both GET and POST
    $this->load->view('theview', $data);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form action = "URL_TO_INDEX_FUNCTION" method = "POST">
    <input type = "text" name = "hi" value = "hi"/>
    <input type = "submit" name = "send" value = "Send"/>
</form>
<?
   if (isset($hi) && $hi != "") 
        echo $hi;
?>
```

Comment: Why not check directly for POST, anyway? Also, all the code you've written is covered by the form_validation library. Mixing good ol' php with framework's way quite defeats the purpose

Comment: Not necessarily, PHP in itself is a framework based on C.  The generalized point of using a framework is SoC and layer abstraction.  Helper classes and libraries exist primarily for rapid development and to store perpetual data, choosing not to use them doesn't necessarily mean you shouldn't use a framework, some just like to keep certain aspects of their code monolithic and localized to PHP itself.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you what you need from the post field,

`$var = $this->input->get_post('some_data', TRUE);`

but if the field is blank (when first entering the page) you might run into a problem with the variable not being defined. So be sure to set the following in your controller:

```
$var = NULL; $var = $this->input->get_post('some_data', TRUE);
$data = array('var' => $var);
$this->load->view('some_view', $data);
```

In the view if you call `echo $var` you should get the output from the post, or nothing if the variable is NULL.